# Send Image with link in Mail as signature.. in Iphone

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send a Image as signature and open a website on click of that Image. Is this possible?

I am succeed to attach image with mail but I don't want attachments.

Is this possible to give link on image and add to mail as signature. In worse case as attachment. I tried http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23272-send-inline-image-link.html

But this is not working too.

Any idea..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this **[POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607165/why-mfmailcomposer-with-img-is-not-showing-the-image-in-mail/6607331#6607331)** I just answered.

I had same problem before couple of weeks and I came to know that Gmail is not supporting embedded images. You can see images in email in other mail provider like your domain email but not in Gmail.

Try to send another email and you can see images. You need to add images as attachment then you can see images and it will display bottom of your email body.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an HTML file that has your image and then load this HTML in email body using `setMessageBody:htmlBody isHTML:YES` ?